# preg_match() match to cases with one pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How would I go about ordering 1 array into 2 arrays depending on what each part of the array starts with using preg_match() ?

I know how to do this using 1 expression but I don't know how to use 2 expressions.
So far I can have done (don't ask why I'm not using strpos() - I need to use regex):

```
$gen =  array(
    'F1',
    'BBC450',
    'BBC566',
    'F2',
    'F31',
    'SOMETHING123',
    'SOMETHING456'
);

$f = array();
$bbc = array();

foreach($gen as $part) {
    if(preg_match('/^F/', $part)) {
        // Add to F array
        array_push($f, $part);
    } else if(preg_match('/^BBC/', $part)) {
        // Add to BBC array
       array_push($bbc, $part);
    } else {
        // Not F or BBC
    }
}
```

So my question is: is it possible to do this using 1 preg_match() function?
Please ignore the SOMETHING part in the array, it's to show that using just one if else statement wouldn't solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: use one function to return either *F* , *BBC* or neither then compare against that

Comment: @Mouser - If I did that, how would I determine whether to push a value into an array or not? Does it return a boolean or something?

Comment: @user3530525  `/^(F)|(BBC)`/ will find a match. `preg_match` has a third parameter called `$matches`. That returns the results founds. You can if/else to push the content in the right array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alternation along with the third argument to `preg_match`, which contains the part of the regexp that matched.

```
preg_match('/^(?:F|BBC)/', $part, $match);
switch ($match) {
case 'F':
    $f[] = $part;
    break;
case 'BBC':
    $bbc[] = $part;
    break;
default:
    // Not F or BBC
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works great. I used this in my foreach loop and the match became an array so I just did $match[0] and it works perfectl! Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1):

It is even possible without any loop, switch, or anything else (which is faster and more efficient then the accepted answer's solution).

```
<?php

preg_match_all("/(?:(^F.*$)|(^BBC.*$))/m", implode(PHP_EOL, $gen), $matches);

$f = isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : array();
$bbc = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[2] : array();
```

You can find an interactive explanation of the regular expression at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vH2rF1/1) which I created for you.

---

The (not desired) `strpos` approach is nearly **five times faster**.

```
<?php

$c = count($gen);
$f = $bbc = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; ++$i) {
  if (strpos($gen[$i], "F") === 0) {
    $f[] = $gen[$i];
  }
  elseif (strpos($gen[$i], "BBC") === 0) {
    $bbc[] = $gen[$i];
  }
}
```

Regular expressions are nice, but the are no *silver bullet* for everything.